# HP Ink manufacture process patent or any other ink manufacturing patent

Tags: manufacturing, printers, ink

Where can I find ink manufacturing process patent compatible with HP.

Comment: Most of this question (production/technology) is outside the focus of this community. However, if you have a more specific question regarding the scope or validity of specific HP patents, or how/where to find a certain type of patent, those questions are fair game here, and we'd be happy to help.

Comment: edits were done. please provide me a patent